# How to make Circular Progress Indicator smaller or bigger in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to make `CircularProgressIndicator` in Jetpack Compose smaller or bigger than default size?

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(32.dp),
)
```

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use:

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
    modifier = Modifier.then(Modifier.size(32.dp))
)
```

[image]

To better describe this solution.
If you look inside the code for `CircularProgressIndicator` (at least in Material 3), you can see the following code:

```
    Canvas(
        modifier
            .progressSemantics()
            .size(CircularIndicatorDiameter)
    ) {
        drawCircularIndicatorTrack(trackColor, stroke)
```

Your provided modifier gets manipulated, and the size is set within the internal code. Due to the [order that the modifiers apply](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraints-modifiers), your `.size()` value is immediately overwritten, hence is ignored.

To work around this, you can use `Modifier.then()` to make Compose evaluate the current modifier, then apply your modifier *after* the internal one. This will make your size modifier work as you expect.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Answer (score 5):

You have to place your `CircularProgressIndicator` into another container:

```
@Composable
private fun LoadingHomeScreen() {
    val strokeWidth = 5.dp

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp),
            color = Color.LightGray,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't make the CircularProgressIndicator smaller or bigger in compose using **Modifier.size(32.dp)** or **Modifier.height(32.dp).width(32.dp)**

use **Modifier.progressSemantics().size(yourDesireSize.dp)**

example

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
    modifier = Modifier
        .progressSemantics()
        .size(32.dp),
)
```

Comment: The semantics modifier is required for an indeterminate progress indicator, that represents the fact of the in-progress operation. It is not related to the size

Comment: Thanks you for the explaination and answer @GabrieleMariotti.

Comment: You don't need the semantics. At least in Material 3 (and I would assume 2 as well), the semantics are applied *on top of* your provided modifier.